# Why can't I connect to mysql via the browser but via the terminal with php?

Tags: mysql, php, webserver, access-control

I would like to display a MySQL table in the browser with PHP and created the  file `demo-db.php`

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<?php
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "fabian";
$password = "XXX";
$dbname = "music";

// Create connection
$conn = mysqli_connect($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
// Check connection
if (!$conn) {
    die("Connection failed: " . mysqli_connect_error());
}
else echo "everything fine";

mysqli_close($conn);
?>

</body>
</html>
```

When I run the file in the terminal with `php -f demo-db.php` I receive the following output:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

everything fine
</body>
</html>
```

Unfortunately, when I navigate to `http://localhost//demo-db.php` I receive the following access denied error:

```
Connection failed: Access denied for user 'fabian'@'localhost'
```

I tried to search the web for help but to no avail. The phpinfo.php file of my machine can be seen [here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/tdmwkuq65utks45/phpinfo%28%29.html?dl=0).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some time, I managed to find one solution to the question:

A comment in [a stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48553789/php-mariadb-access-denied-for-rootlocalhost-through-browser-without-sudo) about accessing a MariaDB database with PHP via a browser states ''newer versions of MariaDB / MySQL don't allow you to use the root user via PHP.'' When using a different user than the root I can indeed connect to the MySQL database as intended.

Answer (score 0):

The issue must be with SELinux, Enable the following boolean.

`setsebool -P httpd_can_network_connect_db=1`

Comment: When I enter the command above, I receive the following message ``setsebool:  SELinux is disabled`` . This [Ask-Ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/481293/selinux-implementation-in-ubuntu) question states that ``SELinux`` is not installed on Ubuntu (the OS I use) but ``apparmor`` is used instead. Do you have any ideas what I can do instead?